# Custom Field is inactive/inaccessible but with proper FLS

Tags: picklist, profile, page-layout, fls

I have a custom picklist field(Program__c) in Account object which is Visible to System Admin profile. However when a System Admin opens an Account record, its appears inactive/inaccessible.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Created a test class(run as SysAdmin) to test where System Admin can
   edit the field, yes, it can.
2. Created a Custom page layout with that
   program__c field and assigned the pagelayout to System Admin, the
   field is still inactive.

Any pointer why the field is not editable for System Admin?

Additional Details:

1. There is another sandbox(Summer15) with exact same configuration and the field is editable there, however this sandbox(Winter15) doesnt allow edit.

Comment: Is there dependency on the piccoloist field?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using record types, and you don't have any values assigned to the pick list for that record type. That seems to be the usual cause.

Comment: That is just awesome! Thank you! If you post this as an Answer I will be more than happy to mark as best answer. Btw, big fan of yours' in stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing one more thing - **might It will work.**

- If you are not able to access your "Program__c" field on any particular VF page
  then (!) Check whether Your VF Page and Its related Controller/Extension has same Version.

Open your Visualforce Page and Apex Class in different tabs of browser 
Click on "Version Settings" tab on detail page of your VF Page and Apex Class - and observ whether both have the same "Version"

Comment: Its not a Visualforce page I am talking about Nilesh, its custom Page Layout.